# ROS code duplication; what are the best practices for this?

Tags: libraries, ros, code-duplication

I was wondering what the best practices is for duplication of code between nodes.

For example:

I grouped together two packages with a metapackage called *perception*, namely; *object detection* and *localization*.

*object detection* package has a node -> **ballDetection**

*localization* package has a node -> **linesDetection**

As you can already assume, there is a lot of code duplication in these nodes. For example, if I want to display images in both nodes to the screen, I have the exact same code in both nodes.

Should I create a library that both nodes can use to display images to the screen? Or should I use nodes for everything? What is the best practice for situations like this?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to create a shared library containing the base code. You then just use the functions/classes from this library in your nodes.

In you CMakeLists.txt you can define a library in the following way:

```
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES <library name>
)
```

...

```
## Declare a C++ library
add_library(<library name>
  src/${PROJECT_NAME}/<cpp file of your library>
  < ... additional files ... >
)
```

Of course don't forget that you need to link dependencies to the library.

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

I also suggest you read through CMakeLists.txt where you have all the instructions on declaring a library.

As for the structure, it doesn't really matter how do you package it. In your specific case I would suggest you to have one catkin package with library and two nodes (you can have multiple nodes in a package). If you think you need to have the library in a separate package, well go ahead. You only need to include to tell catkin you want to include that package as a dependency for the package where you want to use it. You can do this by writing

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ...
  <name of the package with the library>
  ...
)
```

Then you just include the headers from the package in your node (or whatever) files (C++). If you library is NOT header only, then don't forget to link the library against your node with

```
target_link_libraries(
  <node name>
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  <library name>
  ...
)
```

I also suggest reading more about this topic at [ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt).